# Codeigniter join won't work

Tags: database, codeigniter, join

I have a function to get a single user from the database so I can show it, for user profiles and stuff.

Well I want to be able to have a seperate table just for groups, so I can add more if I want to and it be simple. So I have a group_id field in the users table so I can do that, and it would join the groups table with the groups id column.

Well I was able to do it successfully for another project of mine, but when I moved the function over to this current project (I'm using the same EXACT methods to display the profile on both projects) it no longer works... keeps returning nothing at all...

```
public function getUser($username) {
    if (empty($username)) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->ci->db->from('users');
    $this->ci->db->join('groups','users.group_id = groups.id');
    $query = $this->ci->db->where('username',$username)->get();

    $user = $query->row();

    return $user;
}
```

That is the function, could someone please help me as to why it's not working? I have tried it in the controller, the model, and the library, and none of them are working.

Comment: if you do a `return 'test';` instead, does it return the string?

Comment: Yes, if I was to comment out the "$this->ci->db->join('groups','users.group_id = groups.id');" it works just fine, no problems at all

Comment: have you tried something like `return print_r($query)`

Comment: if that doesn't work, then try changing the sql to a simple select *from users, and see if you can at least get something from the db.

Comment: Is there any error you get? Try to log the query to ensure that it's correct using "echo $this->db->last_query();" or "return $this->db->last_query()" after calling get() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel stupid, but anyway I found the issue.

I forgot to actually add a value into the column for that specific user for the group_id

So the group_id in the column was 0, when it needed to be at least 1 or higher, after changing it, it worked just fine...

Thanks for all of your help tho, both of you.